# Nextjs GET request with credentials, API route doesn't receives ( undefined ) cookies while POST request to same route receives correct values

Tags: node.js, next.js, cookies, deployment, vercel

The app works fine on localhost but on deploying to Vercel I face this error that whenever I do a GET request with credentials the API route receives undefined but when I do POST request to same route the cookies are received correctly.

It will be very helpful if someone could explin this to me, thanks in advance :)

Here's Get request ( sends cookie but on API route receives undefined ) :-

```
let reqHeaders = new Headers()
reqHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json")

//GET request
fetch(`${APP_URL}/api/validateLoginSession`,{
    method: "GET",
    headers: reqHeaders,
    credentials: "include"
}).then(it=>{
    it.json().then(resp=>{
        resp.isValid ? onSuccess() : onFailure()
    })
})

// on api/validateLoginSession/route.ts    
export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {

    const userId = req.cookies.get("userId")?.value // receives undefined
    const logToken = req.cookies.get("logToken")?.value // receives undefined

    if (userId && logToken) {
        // ...

    }else{
        // ...
    }

    return new Response(JSON.stringify({isValid: false}))
}
```

But with POST request on same route:

```
// POST request to same route
fetch(`${APP_URL}/api/validateLoginSession`,{
    method: "POST",
    headers: reqHeaders,
    credentials: "include",
    body: JSON.stringify({data: "null"})
}).then(it=>{
    it.json().then(resp=>{
        resp.isValid ? onSuccess() : onFailure()
    })
})

// on api/validateLoginSession/route.ts    
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {

    const reqData = await req.json()
    const userId = req.cookies.get("userId")?.value // receives correct value
    const logToken = req.cookies.get("logToken")?.value // receives correct value

    if (userId && logToken) {
        // ...
    }else{
        // ...
    }

    return new Response(JSON.stringify({isValid: false}))
}
```